# ORACLE database PROFILE

Tags: sql, oracle

How to turn off passwords verification in profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the password verification function, you need to run (assuming `myprofile` is the profile name used):

```
alter profile myprofile limit password_verify_function null;
```

For any other password limit, you need to run for the specific property (here `password_life_time`):

```
alter profile myprofile limit password_life_time unlimited;
```